# How do I preserve Hotkey's base functionality?

Tags: autohotkey, hotkeys

As the below script stands, one would not be able to do much typing without the use of the "t" being used as a hotkey. As it is also one of the most commonly used letters, is there any way to still use two letters as a hotkey while still preserving the individual letters base functionality?

Where:

- letter can be any variable name.
- L1 indicates the maximum allowed length of the input (a single character in this case).
- T2 indicates the number of seconds to wait before terminating the input (2 seconds in this case).

```
$t::
    Input, letter, L1 T2
    If (letter = "h")
        MsgBox, , , You pressed the 't' & 'h'`nkeys in the required time., 5
    else
        MsgBox, , , You pressed 't' but failed to`npress 'h' in the required time., 5
Return
```

Comment: You can replace the key with another one or with a combination of your choise or make it context-sensitive by using the #If- or the #IfWinActive directive.

Comment: To use two letters as a hotkey while still preserving the individual letters base functionality, see [Custom Combinations](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Hotkeys.htm#combo).

Comment: You can also try [RapidHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/35566-rapidhotkey/).

Answer (score 0):

Or this:

```
; Long press of a key to make it wait for another one:

$t::
    Keywait, t, T0.5  ; waits 0.5 seconds maximally for t to be released
    if ErrorLevel     ; pressed for above that time
    {
        KeyWait, t    ; waits for t to be released
        Input, letter, L1 T2
        If (letter = "h")
            MsgBox,,, You pressed the 't' & 'h'`nkeys in the required time., 5
        If (letter = "j")
            MsgBox,,, You pressed the 't' & 'j'`nkeys in the required time., 5              
        else
            MsgBox,,, You pressed 't' but failed to`npress 'h' or 'j'  in the required time., 5
    }
    else
         Send t
Return
```